# suggestions on easy way to add location data to jpegs that will be recognized in iPhone

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, geolocation

I have lots of .jpegs taken either w/ iPhone (location data turned off) or DSLR w/ no location data.  Id like to find an easy way to add the locations to photos so that when synced to iPhone, photos will be searchable by location and show in map on iPhone.  I do not use apple iPhoto app or whatever it might now be called.  Now using last version Catalina

Suggestions?  Tks much.

Comment: RE: "I do not use apple iPhoto app or whatever it might now be called." -- In **macOS Catalina** it's **Photos**, but how are you syncing the files if you're not using it?

Comment: Have a look at: [GeoTa‪g‬](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/geotag/id1465180184?mt=12)

Comment: I sync selected folders via finder using usbc to lightning cable

Answer (score 2):

After saving image to Photos, open the photos app and double click on your image. This opens your image in a new window. You get a window like the one shown below.

[image]

On the top right of the image is a group of icons. Select the first one.  See below.

[image]

When you select the first icon - a circle with the letter i in it you get a new pop up as shown below.

[image]

As you can see at the bottom of this pop up is an area to assign a location.  While this may seem tedious, once you go thru it you'll see how simple it is.

Comment: No I didn't. He said he does not use Photos but he didn't say he would not use photos.  This is a very simple process so I thought if he tried it once he would use it.  But good point. Thanks.

Comment: You may be right - and probably are.  But that wasn't the way i interreted it. i thought he meant he didn't use it because it was complicated. I thought he wouldn't mind a simple process.  But if you think I'm way off base on this i'll just delete my answer.  I respect your opinion on this.  The OP can always down vote it as well.

Comment: Hi Natsfan - I cant tell by following the thread whom you are answering....  But, thanks for the suggestion. I do not use Photos as somewhere long ago I read/heard/ was told / cant remember that it messes with the files somehow.  True or not I don't know for sure but I just assume stay away from it.  I do most of my management - moving, copying, etc., on my own.  I do use Adobe LR and Photoshop a little and have found a way to add the gps info by using Lightroom.  Just figured it out this am.    Tks

Comment: @Stumped I was attempting to answer your question. i know you said you don't use Photos but this was such a simple way to add location that I thought maybe you'd like to give it a try. But thats ok. You may get a better answer anyway.

Comment: Photos messes with the files, BUT it keeps the original.  At any tie, you can select one or more photos and export either the originals or the version modified by the app.  Another reason some don't like the app is that it sucks up a lot of disk space by saving the original, the enhanced version, a thumbnail, a medium-sized version, and separate files for all the faces it can detect.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source item called [exiftool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool) which will let you add location data and a lot more to files.

And while I can no longer remember names, there are tools that will compare timestamps in GPX files with those in images and estimate locations for the photos.  If you find one of those, make a back copy first.  The photos I tried one on were taken in Italy.  My iPad used local time, my sister's Windows tablet used US Colorado time, and the GPS device used UTC.  Result was worse than having no metadata at all.

Answer (score 0):

I do use Adobe LR and Photoshop a little and have found a way to add the gps info by using Lightroom

Comment: Perhaps explaining how to use Lightroom to do this would be useful for others?